# How to get current keyframes time and lastkeyframetime?

Tags: javascript, animation, keyframe

How can I get `currentKeyframeTime` & `lastKeyframeTime` in any animation using Javascript?

I want to update the `currentKeyframeTime` of my animation to some other time because i'm making a tracking bar for animation, similar to a player slider like in youtube so I need the `currentKeyframeTime` and `lastKeyframeTime`.

I have successfully done this for audio, as it has `currentTime` & `duration` type properties. What code I should write to get `currentKeyframeTime` & `lastKeyFrameTime`?

Comment: Fixed question grammar and added some formatting

Answer (score 0):

You would keep track of the time elapsed like so: http://plnkr.co/edit/CfOttpMPelxS1iYnnEPW

```
(function(){
  var currentFrame, startTime;

  function animate(){
      console.log('Previous Frame Happened At: ' + currentFrame);
      currentFrame = Date.now() - startTime;
      console.log('Current time elapsed since start: ' + currentFrame);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  startTime = Date.now();
  currentFrame = startTime;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
})();
```